# Interpretation of the radius of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, definition

What interpretation should one give to the radius of convergence of a series $\sum a_nz^n$ ?

I do know how it is mathematically defined and what it implies for convergence/divergence, but I'm having a hard time understanding what its meaning is behind the formulas.

Is there, for instance, a graphical interpretation, or something of that kind ?

Comment: For a complex series the series converge for all points within a circle of radius = radius of convergence. For example $\sum z^n$ converge for all points within the circle $|z| < 1$ or $x^2 +y^2 < 1$ ($x,y$ being the real/imaginary parts of $z$)

Comment: @Winther As I pointed out in the edit, I already know that. I can't really extract a "meaning" from it, other than "it converges when it's in the open disk of convergence". I'm looking for a somewhat deeper meaning (if there is any). For instance, one could say that the derivative is the ratio $dy/dx$; that is true, but does not give a hold on what the derivative really is.

Comment: OK. One interpretation is that it gives the distance to the nearest pole of the analytic (withtin the radius of convergence) function it respresents.

Comment: the fundamental idea is that general power series behave a lot like geometric series $\sum r^n$ which we know converges for $|r|<1$ since otherwise the terms grow 'too quickly' for the sum to settle towards a steady state. for general power series, we similarly want $a_n z^n=(\sqrt[n]{a_n}z)^n$ to behave sufficiently 'like' $r^n$ for some real $|r|<1$, i.e. we want $|\sqrt[n]{a_n}z|=|\sqrt[n]{a_n}||z|<1$ in the 'long run' as $n\to\infty$. the values $z$ for which this possible naturally give $|z|\le1/R$ for some $R$, and this is our radius of convergence

Answer (score 0):

First the radius of convergence is defined for a power series but not for whatever series. Then the power series converge inside the disk of convergence, the one centered in zero and having for radius the radius of convergence. And it diverges outside this disk.

Comment: I know that, that's what I called the "formulas". I know how it's defined for series of the kind $\sum a_nz^n$, and what it implies for convergence/divergence.

Comment: Interesting topic is that the location of convergence is a disk and not whatever strange geometrical location!